# Autofac – Scan and batch register generic types

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, autofac

In my project I’ve got the following base class for all my repositories:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TContext, TEntity> : Disposable, IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
        where TContext : DbContext, new()
    {...}
```

The repositories inheriting form the base class do not specify a DB context type (because the context is not the same for all applications):

```
public class UserRepository<TContext> : RepositoryBase<TContext, User>
    where TContext : BaseContext, new()
{
    public UserRepository( IDatabaseFactory<TContext> databaseFactory, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory )
        : base( databaseFactory, loggerFactory )
    {...}
}

public class ProductRepository<TContext> : RepositoryBase<TContext, Product>
    where TContext : BaseContext, new()
{...}
```

I know autofac is able to register all types matching some criteria like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes( assembly )
    .Where(...)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Is there a way to do the same for all types inheriting from RepositoryBase for a specific context?
Something like:

```
public class MyContext : BaseContext { }
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes( assembly )
    .Where(...)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces(/*specify  MyContext as TContext*/);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is TContext known for types inheriting from RepositoryBase? If you know UserRepository will use MyContext, and ProductRepository will use MyOtherContext, you could define them as such and have Autofac pick them up automatically:

```
public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase<MyContext, User>
{...}

public class ProductRepository : RepositoryBase<MyOtherContext, Product>
{...}
```

Otherwise I assume you have a requirement to allow data from multiple contexts?

```
public class MyContextUserRepository : RepositoryBase<MyContext, User>
{...}

public class MyOtherContextUserRepository : RepositoryBase<MyOtherContext, User>
{...}
```

In which case you can define them as above, but on resolve you'll have to pass in the context you want in that particular scenario

```
public class MyClass
{
    readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;

    public MyClass(IRepository<User> userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
}

var myClass = _container.Resolve<MyClass>(
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (x, y) => x.ParameterType == typeof (IRepository<User>),
                    (x, y) => y.Resolve<MyContextUserRepository>()));
```

Or you could do this on registration, in which case you may find the [Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html) useful.

**Edit after comments**

Okay so you have multiple applications that share a common library containing interfaces, implementations, and entities. A given application can define their implementations and entities, but will have only one context that is specific to that application.

```
// your application specific context
public class MySpecificApplicationContext : DbContext { }

// get your entity types that a given application uses
var entityTypes = GetEntityTypes();

// register a repository implementation for each entity type
// note RepositoryBase is not abstract for this example
for (var i = 0; i < entityTypes.Count; i++)
{
    var entityType = entityTypes[i];
    builder
        .RegisterType(typeof (RepositoryBase<,>)
        .MakeGenericType(typeof (MySpecificApplicationContext), entityType))
        .As(typeof (IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}

// resolve an entity repository
var userRepository = container.Resolve<IRepository<User>>();
```

Comment: TContext is not known for neither repository types nor the types resolving and using the repositories.
(The same repositories are used in multiple applications for different contexts).
TContext is only known during registration. I can’t find any information about my problem in the documentation.

Comment: You mention 'The same repositories are used in multiple applications for different contexts'. In a given application do you have multiple contexts or one?

Comment: And do you have different implementations for your repositories in a given application? E.g. application 1 may contain AnimalRepository and application 2 may contain BookRepository? Or do your applications all share the same entities and repositories - e.g. all have the same User entity and all have a UserRepository

Comment: No they do not share all the repositories. (The repositories are part of a library providing some common features… if the application uses a feature => it needs the repositories used by those features.)

Comment: Are the implementations of the IRepository in your library too? E.g. does your library contain the implementations UserRepository and ProductRepository, or are the implementations defined in a given application.

Comment: The implementations are part of the library. BUT the applications themselves do implement the interfaces as well for application specific entities.

Comment: Edited answer... hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.